# How to add a column in a df with mapped values from identical column in df2?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames `categories` and `data` and would like to add a column to `data` based on a column of `categories`. Here's some of the information for these data frames.

```
items: DataFrame | (22170, 3) | Column names: item_name, item_id, item_category_id
data:  DataFrame | (2935849, 6) | Column names: date, date_block_num, shop_id, item_id, item_price, item_cnt_day
```

There are 83 categories of items and 22169 unique items. I would like `item_category_id` to be added to data with its values uniquely equated to each `item_id`. I have gone through some of the posts here at SO but they seem perfect for smaller datasets or sets that require simpler mapping. What I'm looking for is this:

```
print(data.head())
date   shop_id  item_id  item_category_id -> # Newly added column
D.M.Y  50       22142    32
D.M.Y  25       521      12
D.M.Y  25       541      57
.
. 
D.M.Y  44       42       83
```

`merge` seems to be good enough, but it merges all of the data and them removing the unneeded columns makes the process inefficient. Whats a nice way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `merge` only on the slices of your DataFrames containing the columns that you need in the final result:

```
data_cols = ['date', 'shop_id', 'item_id']
items_cols = ['item_id', 'item_category_id']

pd.merge(data[data_cols], items[items_cols], how='left', on='item_id')
```

Alternatively, you could create a lookup dictionary (or Series) then use `map`:

```
lookup = dict(zip(items['item_id'], items['item_category_id']))
data['item_category_id'] = data['item_id'].map(lookup)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `merge` is your best option. In terms of efficiency, maybe try `merge` followed by the simple but effective

```
df = df[['date', 'shop_id', 'item_id', 'item_category_id']]
```